# Android: Are there any benefits to using @id over @+id performance wise?

Tags: android, xsd

I know that the + in @+id tells the compiler to add the id to the (R.id.???) resources. However i was wondering if there were performance benefits to be gained by not putting the + ?

Perhaps for example when dealing with complex list view layouts?

Comment: I don't think so, the only performance boost would be the compile time no effect on the app itself.

Comment: Thanks schwiz, I might have to rephrase the question as everyone's telling me what i already posted in the question itself. I "KNOW" what the + signifies, and how to use it. The question was "is there a performance gain using @id over @+id"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the difference. If you use `android:id` it should always be `@+id` (I think). That means you're assigning it an ID. Otherwise, as raybritton said, you're referencing an ID.

But also, R is generated even before compile time. Not only would the benefits be minuscule, but they would come at compile time and not at run time so it doesn't matter.

Comment: I think you nailed it with the fact that the R is generated before  compile time, which makes it almost obvious that @+id is no different from @id when running the app. Doh.

Comment: Could you link to the android documentation describing the difference between `@+id` and `id`? (It's hard to google because symbols.)

Answer (score 3):

The + means add to R list, without you're referencing an already existing UI element, in other words @+id/ != @id/

Answer (score 2):

There are no performance differences at all.  For IDs, the only reason to not use '+' is if you are declaring an ID explicitly and want to reference it, ensuring all references are to that particular ID.  For example, if you don't use '+' and have a typo in your ID name, you will get a compile-time error, while with a '+' a new entry for the typo'd ID will be created.

Answer (score 1):

By using @+id you are adding a reference to R, by using @id you will reuse an already existing reference in a generated R class. This can be done, for instance, to inform your activity where to find a specific widget in a layout, as it is the case when using a custom layout with ListActivity. You will then assign your ListView an already existing id of @id/android:list which is a predefined. Same goes with TabHost and TabWidget.

For the rest, no performance difference, I think...